# Why would kubernetes OOM kill a pause container?

Tags: kubernetes, out-of-memory, google-kubernetes-engine

Occasionally our Kubernetes cluster (1.12.7 on GKE) emits an event like:

```
1 OOMKilling: Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 605624 (pause) score 0 or sacrifice child
Killed process 605624 (pause) total-vm:1024kB, anon-rss:4kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

At exactly the same time we see an event from Docker:

```
datadog/agent@sha256:904c18135ec534fc81c29a42537725946b23ba19ac3c0a8b2e942fe39981af20 1 oom 1 kill 1 die 1 stop 1 destroy 1 create 1 start on gke-prod-pool-1-dc20d284-sjwm...

OOM     k8s_datadog-agent_datadog-agent-76v8c_default_bf678779-c318-11e9-b064-42010a9a0059_7  
KILL    k8s_datadog-agent_datadog-agent-76v8c_default_bf678779-c318-11e9-b064-42010a9a0059_7  
...
```

The `datadog-agent` pod is also restarted.

This particular pod is configured with guaranteed QoS. According to the table under [Node OOM Behaviour on this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/), a guaranteed pod should have an oom score of -998.

Why is the pause container being killed here? And since it appears to be  the pause container for the `datadog-agent` pod, why is the oom score 0, not -998?

Comment: `pause` is a container, so when you see in the error message `killing pause` it already tells me that it's not k8s killing it. OOM killer will kill the process with most memory in use. Since `pause` is the container in charge of keeping the pod active (probably datadog pod), it is the principal process which the other processes (containers) are pinned to, so the kernel thinks by killing it, most memory will be freed. Do you have resource requests and limits set? If not, do it.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't appreciated that the oom killer was part of the node kernel. The pod has memory requests and limits both set to 512MiB, which implies the `Guaranteed` QoS setting. According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/, `kubelet` should have assigned the containers in the pod  an `oom_score_adj` of -998. Could this be a bug?

Comment: It might be a bug in COS, or a transient issue. Can you replicate it by forcing another OOM? Also, which other pods were running on the node, do you know if there were other containers running on the node with lower QoS?

Comment: I might be able to replicate -- do you mean force OOM in the datadog container? There are definitely other pods on the node with lower QoS.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has its mechanism to specify min and max requirements for containers; for example, you can have:

```
 resources:
    limits: 150M
 requests:
    memory: 50M
```

When your pod crosses the line of the maximum "limit" the pod will get killed and reported as OOM-Killed, it doesn't really matter if you have enough memory or not; as you already investigated this feed the OOM Killer process by giving them scores, the higher score the most likely that process will be terminated and, viceversa, the lower the score, the less likely is that it will be sent to the slaughter house (thus using negative values for processes that you want to preserve); since this is not all what is got, the kernel also has some oom_score_adj to be tweaked and control, let's say, artificially, the score and to preserve or not say process in the killing line.

When the memory limit is set for a pod, K8s issues an OOM_SCORE_ADJ value based on, what you correctly state, QoS (burstable) to ensure such specific container gets selected by the OOMK and gets killed.

Finally, to address the score question, on why it gets such score, this "table" maybe of use for you:

```
 +------------------+------------------------+
 |     QoS          |           Score        |
 |  (Setting)       |     (Value or formula) |
 +-------------------------------------------+
 | Guaranteed       |           -998         |
 +-------------------------------------------+
 | Best effort      |           1000         |
 +-------------------------------------------+
 | Burstable        |          Formula       |
 +------------------+------------------------+
```

Where Score formula for Burstable es equals to:

```
 min( max(2, 1000 - (1000 * mRB) / mMCB), 999)
 mRB = Memory Request Bytes.
 mMCB = Machine Memory Capacity Bytes
```

And since QoS for GKE/Kubernetes is burstable, well, that's how it gets in line for the killing room.

I trust this information will be useful for you, but I recommend also to check out the following links:
[1] OOR-Node OOM Behavior (Kubernetes.io)
[2] Container and pod memory assignation

Regards!

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#node-oom-behavior

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#exceed-a-containers-memory-limit

Comment: I understand how the oom killer works generally (I think). This particular case confuses me because the `datadog-agent` pod has a Guaranteed QoS -- limit and requests set to 512MiB. So why was the _pause_ container killed? And why was the score 0? It is a suspiciously round number...

Comment: That behavior leads me to think something is odd about resources perhaps? have you checked those pods? The resource requests and limits match what you have available? or perhaps (since I believe data dog is a collection agent) you may need to add some resources to avoid the pod killing since it may not have the "power" to carry on thus getting removed?

Comment: Clearly there is memory pressure on the node and the `datadog-agent` pod is being oomkilled before anything can be evicted. My question is not why something is being killed, but why this pod specifically is being killed. The pod is configured as Guaranteed, so its containers should get a score of -998. But the `pause` container being killed belonged to this pod, and apparently had a score of 0.

Comment: The system will determine those on best-effort and choose those first, that's the theory, but if needed it actually can kill something else based on resource allocation; so yeah, the system can murder a process (after all containers are just that, processes) you have low resources trying to be assigned and you have your guaranteed class on those pods but no more resources are left; and you don't have (supposedly) B-E class processes left, then what it does? goes for the rest.  Verify your class just to be sure: kubectl get pod MYPOD -o jsonpath='{.status.qosClass}'

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. But something still seems wrong here. Firstly, there were other pods that were not killed, which should have had higher scores. Secondly, why did the the pause container associated with a guaranteed pod have a score of zero? If I understand the docs correctly, the score should have been -998.

Comment: It would be necessary to check their score; the score goes up to 1000, the higher the score, the more likely it is the process is to be killed; so the oom_score_adj set to -998 means that the score is adjusted to -998 which results in 0. Lower value means it is less likely to be killed, but if all the processes are at 0, one of them still has to go (or not just one, many). Thanks a lot for your comments! Hope the information was useful for you.